# Refresh the page data when you go to this page in the flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to write a small application in which I collect data through api. I take the data, everything works. I decided to make a navigation bar to switch between pages. But when I try on the pages they are empty. In order for the data to be updated on the page, I need to click "Hot reload". I will be grateful for your help.
My main.dart:

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/model/dataArea_list/JsonDataArea.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/model/object_list/JsonObject.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/model/seals_list/JsonSeals.dart';
 
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());

}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home: new HomeScreen());
  }
}
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Журнал пломби'),
      ),
      // body: Seals(),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
                title: Text("Seals List"),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Seals()),
                  );
                }
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}



class Seals extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home:JsonParseSeals(),

    );
  }
}
```

My modul Seals:

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/model/seals_list/SealsListGet.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/model/seals_list/ServicesSeals.dart';
 

class JsonParseSeals extends StatefulWidget {
  //
  JsonParseSeals() : super();


  @override
  _JsonParseSealsState createState() => _JsonParseSealsState();
}

class _JsonParseSealsState extends State <StatefulWidget> {
  //
  List<SealList> _seals;
  bool _loading;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _loading = true;
    Services.getSeals().then((seals) {
      _seals =seals;
      _loading = false;
    }
    );

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Список пломби'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
          itemCount: null == _seals ? 0 :_seals.length,
          itemBuilder: (_,index)  => Card(
            color: Colors.red[300],
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7),
            child:ListTile(
                title: Text(_seals[index].sealNumber,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
            ),
            subtitle:  Text(
                "${_seals[index].used}" ),
            leading: Icon(Icons.local_activity,
              size: 40,
              color: Colors.black87,
            ),
            ),
        ),

    ),

    );
  }
}
```

My code : [image]
[image]

Code after change:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your data updated after you apply Hot reload, right?

Comment: @fartem yes,after  apply Hot reload

Comment: @Doc I work with a flutter, very little time, so I can not answer this question, I did this project by example. I will be grateful if you tell me how to do it right!

Comment: You need to use state management for it. Because you have shared data and you pass this data to another screens, you need to have a place with this data and manipulate it globally. Start from [Official Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).

Comment: @fartem I understood little, maybe you have similar devices?

Comment: You need to share data with devices?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228879/discussion-between-maksingenr-and-fartem).

Comment: @fartem Yes, this application will have some options. The first option, I use the GET method to take away directories by API (it will be 2 directories), I want to display these directories in a list. And the second option, to write down data through API by the POST method, having sent there a photo (made through the appendix) and number of a seal which I have to choose in one of downers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap your screen with data in `FutureBuilder` (you can read more about this widget [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)):

```dart
class _JsonParseSealsState extends State <StatefulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<SealList>>(
      future: Services.getSeals(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Data is loading, you should show progress indicator to a user
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        // Data is loaded, handle it
        return ListView.builder(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            final item = snapshot.data[index];
            return Card(
              color: Colors.red[300],
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  item.sealNumber,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                ),
                subtitle:  Text("${item.used}"),
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.local_activity,
                  size: 40,
                  color: Colors.black87,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hello friend, thank you for helping, but I have another question that I can not solve, and would be grateful if you helped me with this))) I want to add a search on the card, but I can not implement it, could would you help me with this ?? I even made a nome question on this issue.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66867248/search-with-filter-card-data-from-api-for-flutter

Comment: @MaksIngenr can you create a new question with your problem?